# Only show rows if it contains text

Tags: php, html

A part of my site displays a list of everyone who registered, but some of the names don't have their first and last names in it because they did not finish registration. Currently I have it so it displays every single on in the list and it shows ones with names and without so I have a lot of blank ones. How can I make it only show ones with text in the actual name field?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include "../newsmile/db.php";
$select = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from register where status = '0'");
$count = 1;

while($select1= mysqli_fetch_array($select))
{
    $selectname = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from shipping_detail where User_id = '".$select1['id']."'");
    $selectname1= mysqli_fetch_array($selectname);
    echo '<tr>
        <td class="center">'.$count.'</td>
        <td>'.$selectname1['First_name']." ".$selectname1['Last_name'].'</td>
        <td>
            <div class="panel-body buttons-widget">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info userinfo" id = "'.$select1['id'].'">Info
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>';
    $count++;                                                   
}

?>
```

Comment: the first thing wrong here is the 2nd query in a loop, you could get all the rows with one query using a join and loop that

Comment: @rtfm But how would I make it only display if they actually have text in the first name column ?

Comment: do you still want to select them if they dont have any text in the first name column?

Comment: @rtfm Nope, I don't want them to display at all, only ones thats have text in the first name column should display.

Comment: so dont select them in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a guard statement before you output the row

```
while($select1= mysqli_fetch_array($select))
{
    $selectname = mysqli_query(
        $con,
        "SELECT * from shipping_detail where User_id = '".$select1['id']."'"
    );
    $selectname1= mysqli_fetch_array($selectname);

    if (empty($selectname1['First_name'])) {
        continue;
    }

    if (empty($selectname1['Last_name'])) {
        continue;
    }

    echo '<!-- table row here -->';
    $count++;
}
```

You also have a n+1 problem you should fix.

Comment: Awesome, This worked, and can you elaborate more on the n+1 problem?

Comment: why select db rows your dont want to use? better to exclude them in the querry

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SQL string concatenation, It cause you security issues
If you set the default value for first name and last name column as null, you can try something like following

```
while($select1= mysqli_fetch_array($select))
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from shipping_detail where User_id = ? and first_name<>null and last_name<>null");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $select1['id']);
//   i - integer
//   d - double
//   s - string
//   b - BLOB



$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($selectname1= $result ->fetch_array())
        {


    echo '<tr>
        <td class="center">'.$count.'</td>
        <td>'.$selectname1['First_name']." ".$selectname1['Last_name'].'</td>
        <td>
            <div class="panel-body buttons-widget">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info userinfo" id = "'.$select1['id'].'">Info
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>';

        }   
     $count++;    
     $stmt->close();                                               
}
```

If you didn't set the default value, change query as follows

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from shipping_detail where User_id = ? and first_name<>'' and last_name<>''");
```

You can read about this **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)**